# From where can I get english translation of Sri Ramakrishna Paramhamsadever Jivanvrttanta by Ram Chandra Datta?

Tags: resource, ramakrishna

Sri Ramakrishna Paramhamsadever Jivanvrttanta, written by Ram Chandra Datta is regarded as the first biography of Ramakrishna. It goes into great detail about the sadhanas done by Ramakrishna. I want to get the English translation of this book. Pdf or digital will also work.

Comment: I don't think it's available in English. After whatever, the author mentioned about Paramahamsa - it was outrageous, scandalous and reports of lawsuits against the writer have been talked about. It can only be read in Bengali, I guess, as far as any published work goes.

Comment: @Vivikta no no. I don't think so. Even RKM website praise the author Ram Chandra Datta and his biography of Ramakrishna. RKM even sell the bengali version. About the scandalous part, it's only claimed by jeffery kripal the western "researcher" who wrote controversial Kali's child. Don't take his words seriously. Even RKM refuted his book point by point. Some other haters like narasingha sil have written the same for Ramakrishna's sadhnas. But they can be refuted easily.

Comment: @Vivikta also I think english version is available it was translated recently but it's rare.

Comment: Yes, the allegations, might be false maybe. In any case, the Advaita-ashrama only sells the Bengali version. So, which publisher is selling the English ones?

Comment: @Vivikta idk but i remember one online. Maybe it was translated by some RK devotee like kathamrita.org?

Comment: Resources seem really scant, can't find. Even I wanted that translation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is available in amazon. It has been translated in English by Swami Sarvadevananda and one other person in 2014.

- The Life Story of Sri Ramakrishna Hardcover – 7 July 2014
  by Ramchandra Dutta (Author), English rendering based on the translation by Swami Sarvadevananda (Author), Pulak Ghosh (Editor)

[Amazon Link here](https://www.amazon.in/Life-Story-Sri-Ramakrishna/dp/8175054220/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2F1D67W618TIH&keywords=Ramchandra+Dutta&qid=1645016308&s=books&sprefix=ramchandra+dutta+%2Cstripbooks%2C699&sr=1-1)

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, Pradip Ji! :))

Comment: Thanks sir. That answers my question. Is there any traditional translation available in public? Like those of Kathamrita and Leelaprasanga?

Comment: I am not aware of any.